# Python - how to multiply daily values in dataframe with hourly percentages in a dictionary to get dataframe with hourly values

Tags: python, dataframe, dictionary

I have a dataframe of daily transit ridership data for each station of a city and I also have a dictionary with the hourly ridership distribution in percentages.

I would like to create a dataframe of hourly transit ridership for each station by multiplying the daily ridership values in the dataframe with the hourly predictions in the dictionary.

For instance, the data frame looks as follows:

```
    Austin-Forest Park  Harlem-Lake
date        
2018-11-01  2248.0  4021.0
2018-11-02  1983.0  3850.0
2018-11-03  837.0   2308.0
2018-11-04  604.0   1443.0
```

And the hourly percentage ridership distribution looks like this
with each key/value combination being a certain hour and % of daily ridership.

```
hourly_distribution = {0:0.017, 1:0.017, 2:0.008, 3:0.008, 4:0.004, 
                          5:0.004, 6:0.008, 7:0.021, 8:0.051, 9:0.042,
                          10:0.042, 11:0.038, 12:0.034, 13:0.038, 14:0.051, 
                          15:0.068, 16:0.084, 17:0.11, 18:0.101, 19:0.084,
                          20:0.059, 21:0.051, 22:0.034, 23:0.025}


hourly_distribution_weekend_days = {0:0.015, 1:0.015, 2:0.008, 3:0.008,4:0.008, 5:0.008, 
                         6:0.015, 7:0.023, 8:0.038, 9:0.046, 10:0.054, 
                         11:0.077, 12:0.092, 13:0.092, 14:0.092, 15:0.092,
                         16:0.062, 17:0.054, 18:0.054, 19:0.054, 20:0.031, 
                         21:0.031, 22:0.015, 23:0.015}
```

My expected outcome would then be this for Austin-Forest Park on 2018-11-01:

```
    Austin-Forest Park
Date    
2018-11-01 00:00:00 38.2
2018-11-01 01:00:00 38.2
2018-11-01 02:00:00 18.0
2018-11-01 03:00:00 18.0
2018-11-01 04:00:00 9.0
2018-11-01 05:00:00 9.0
2018-11-01 06:00:00 18.0
2018-11-01 07:00:00 47.2
2018-11-01 08:00:00 114.6
2018-11-01 09:00:00 94.4
2018-11-01 10:00:00 94.4
2018-11-01 11:00:00 85.4
2018-11-01 12:00:00 76.4
2018-11-01 13:00:00 85.4
2018-11-01 14:00:00 114.6
2018-11-01 15:00:00 152.9
2018-11-01 16:00:00 188.8
2018-11-01 17:00:00 247.3
2018-11-01 18:00:00 227.0
2018-11-01 19:00:00 188.8
2018-11-01 20:00:00 132.6
2018-11-01 21:00:00 114.6
2018-11-01 22:00:00 76.4
2018-11-01 23:00:00 56.2
```

From this small sample, the expected shape of the new dataframe would then be (96,2) with 2 columns and 4 days x 24 hours of hourly ridership values.

Would anyone have any idea how to write this in Python?

Thank you!

Comment: If you provide the input for your dataframe, life will be easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagining you have following dataframe definition:

```py
import pandas as pd

df_daily = pd.Series([2248, 1983, 837, 604], index=pd.date_range(start='2018-11-01', end='2018-11-04'))
```

You can do:

```py
df_daily = (
    df_daily
        .resample('H', closed='right').ffill()
        .to_frame(name='park')
        .assign(hour=lambda df: df.index.hour)
        .apply(lambda x: hourly_distribution[x['hour']]*x['park'], axis=1)
)

df_daily
```

[image]

**Explanation:**

- First, you upsample your data to an hourly basis using resample. .fffill will use the day value for all hours.
- Then you create a column named *hour*.
- You use *hour* column to find equivalent percentage on hourly_distribution dictionary and multiply it by total day visitors that I just called *park*.

Comment: Hi Victor, thank you so much. It worked perfectly. I have another question. What if have a second dictionary with the weekend hourly ridership distribution? How would I tell Python to first check the date for being a business day of weekend day (i.e. Saturday and Sunday) so it knows which dictionary to use to get the hourly transit ridership values? For instance, in the sample dataframe in the question, the 2018-11-03 and 2011-11-04 are weekend days. I've added the second dictionary in the question. Thanks again.

Comment: @LeonPoon Dude, you got your question answered. Accept this answer and make a new question.

Comment: @JossieCalderon sorry, wasn't aware that this is inappropriate behavior.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`numpy.outer`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.outer.html) for the product and list comprehension with [`pandas.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html) to build the new datetime index as follow:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime

idx = pd.to_datetime(['2018-11-01', '2018-11-02', '2018-11-03', '2018-11-04'])
df_daily = pd.DataFrame({'Austin-Forest Park': [2248.0, 1983.0, 837.0, 604.0],
                         'Harlem-Lake': [4021.0, 3850.0, 2308.0, 1443.0]},
                         index=idx)
df_daily.index.name = 'date'


hourly_distribution = {0:0.017, 1:0.017, 2:0.008, 3:0.008, 4:0.004,
                          5:0.004, 6:0.008, 7:0.021, 8:0.051, 9:0.042,
                          10:0.042, 11:0.038, 12:0.034, 13:0.038, 14:0.051,
                          15:0.068, 16:0.084, 17:0.11, 18:0.101, 19:0.084,
                          20:0.59, 21:0.051, 22:0.034, 23:0.025}

distrib = [hourly_distribution[key] for key in hourly_distribution]

datetime_idx = pd.to_datetime([datetime.datetime(i.year, i.month, i.day, key) for i in idx for key in hourly_distribution])
data = np.outer(df_daily['Austin-Forest Park'], distrib).ravel()

df = pd.DataFrame({'Austin-Forest Park': data}, index=datetime_idx)
df.index.name = 'date'
```

which outputs

```
                     Austin-Forest Park
date                                   
2018-11-01 00:00:00              38.216
2018-11-01 01:00:00              38.216
2018-11-01 02:00:00              17.984
2018-11-01 03:00:00              17.984
2018-11-01 04:00:00               8.992
...                                 ...
2018-11-04 19:00:00              50.736
2018-11-04 20:00:00             356.360
2018-11-04 21:00:00              30.804
2018-11-04 22:00:00              20.536
2018-11-04 23:00:00              15.100

[96 rows x 1 columns]
```